# is there any way to make DIV automatically adjust its size to wrap text?

Tags: html, css

I have a div which has some text, but according to different situations this box can have different amounts of text contained within it. is there any way to make a div adjust its size in order to wrap the text that it contains.

Comment: You may have everything, but we need some example code to work upon.

Comment: The way you describe it, that would happen all by itself. So are there some conditions you're not mentioning?

Comment: that's exactly how a `div` works unless you specify a width and/or height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that is better if you just use the height.

```
.Class {height:auto;}
```

if you use width:auto, your webpage will distort and it won't look so good, so you could use width if you use a fixed width like

```
.Class {height:auto; width: 700px;}
```

or something like that

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap it into another container and let the browser handle the size by not applying height/width values.

Answer (score 0):

Try one of these

@CSS3 Resize:

```
.divClass {resize:both;}
```

or

```
.divClass {width:auto; height:auto;min-width:100px;}
```

Comment: hi, the width is being set at body level to 950px, and this container is inherting it from the body. in any case the maximum width needed for this div is either 160px or 200px. any way to prevent it from inheriting it from its parent?